# GROUP_CONCAT with dplyr or R

Tags: sql, r, dplyr, group-concat

I am having difficulty replicating the functionality of a typical SQL GROUP_CONCAT function in dplyr. I would also like to make sure the ordering inside the groups can be controlled. Ideally I want to use the hadleyverse/tidyverse but base R or other packages will work too.

Example data:

```
ID    name
1     apple
1     orange
2     orange
3     orange
3     apple
```

Desired output:

```
ID    name
1     apple,orange
2     orange
3     apple,orange
```

Note that for ID=3, the ordering is in alpha order, not how the rows are ordered. I think this can probably be handled by doing an `arrange` first, but it would be nice to control inside the `summarise` statement or the like.

Answer (score 10):

In `R`, we can use one of the group by operations.

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>%
    group_by(ID) %>%
    summarise(name = toString(sort(unique(name))))
#     ID          name 
#   <int>         <chr>
#1     1 apple, orange
#2     2        orange
#3     3 apple, orange
```

---

Or using `data.table`

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df1)[, .(name = toString(sort(unique(name)))), by = ID]
#   ID          name
#1:  1 apple, orange
#2:  2        orange
#3:  3 apple, orange
```

Comment: nice answer , I like the data.table

Comment: I think `stringr::str_c()` can also be used : `str_c(unique(name), collapse="; "))` - this allows the user to specify a custom separator .

Answer (score 1):

For base R use this

```
aggregate(data=df,name~ID,FUN = function(t) sort(paste(t)))
```

**Data**

```
df<-read.table(header = T,text = "ID    name
1     apple
1     orange
2     orange
3     orange
3     apple")
```